# Can not connect MongoDB container from in the same container on AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I created two container in AWS EC2. One for MongoDB and the other one is for Fast API.

I can connect MongoDB container from Fast API container because when sent POST method it accepts end returns 201, but I did not create GET method to see if it is created or not.

The problem is when connect to MongoDB container from the AWS EC2 with `sudo docker exec -it <mongodb container> sh` and try to connect mongo with my username and password that my Fast API container's uses it, it throws "authorization failed" error.

Here is the Fast API connection string to MongoDB;
`mongodb://kek:1234@mongoDB:10511/dbName?authSource=admin`

Here is the mongo connection string;`mongosh --port 10511 -u kek -p 1234 --authenticationDatabase  dbName`

This is mongo docker-compose file;

```
  mongoDB:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --port 10511
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: kek
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dbName
    ports:
      - "10511:10511"


  fastAPI:
    build: /backend
    ports:
      - "40050:80"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=dbName
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://kek:1234@mongoDB:10511/dbName?authSource=admin
    depends_on:
      - mongoDB
```

I can connect mongo with this; `mongosh --port 10511` (in the MongoDB container), but I can't do anything because of authorization issue.

***EDIT-1:***

I tried;

```
use dbName
db.auth('kek','1234')
```

and same, still authentication error.

***EDIT-2:***

I found log:

> "error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "kek" for db "dbName""

Comment: `authenticationDatabase  admin`?

Comment: @dododo I tried and same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it.
I know it's silly but I'm learning docker so I hope it will help other newbie.

I was creating my environment variable between " not ' on AWS EC2 side. So use '